# Ag Grid React Cell Renderer with Array Values into One Cell

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an object I want to display using Ag Grid data table. The object is only one row of data for table.

```
0: {appID: 12345, blocker_issues: Array(2), crtitical_issues: Array(2), major_issues: Array(2), minor_issues: Array(2), …}

eg: 
{appID: 123456,
blocker_issues:  [554, -1563],
crtitical_issues:[3522, -3058],
duplication:     [1322494, '-471d'],
lines_of_code:  [374993, '-471d'],
major_issues:  [16581, -10864],
minor_issues: [14381, -9658],
tech_debt:  [26.3, '+16.26']}
```

Ag Grid details :

```
   const [columndefs] = useState([
        { field: 'appID', headerName: 'App ID', cellRenderer: CustomElements },
        { field: 'blocker_issues', headerName: 'Blocker Issues', cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'critical_issues', headerName: 'Critical Issues',  cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'major_issues', headerName: 'Major Issues', cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'minor_issues', headerName: 'Minor Issues',cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'tech_debt', headerName: 'Tech Debt', cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'lines_of_code', headerName: 'Lines Of Code', cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' },
        { field: 'duplications', headerName: 'Duplications', cellRenderer: SplitCellRenderer, cellDataType: 'object' }
    ]);


 return (
        parsedAppData?(<div
        id = "appStats"
        className = 'ag-theme-* bordered'
        style = {{ paddingTop: '1rem', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        > <AgGridReact onGridReady={onGridReady} gridOptions={gridoptions} rowData={parsedAppData} />
    </div >
    ) : ''
```

I created a cell renderer that I want to add both values to the same cell, with the second value being either green or red conditionally.

```
 function SplitCellRenderer(props) {
        if (props.value !== undefined) {
            return <span>{props.value[0]}
                <span style={changeColor(props.value[1])}>
                    {` (${props.value[1]})`}
                </span></span>
        }
    }

 const changeColor = (val) => {
        if (val > 0) return { color: "red" };
        return { color: "#02b013" };
    };
```

I get the error :
`AG Grid: Cell data type is "object" but no value formatter has been provided. Please either provide an object data type definition with a value formatter, or set "colDef.valueFormatter"`
so I added dataType as object but do I need a formatter if I want to use cell Renderer ? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the "cellDataType" to either to false to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Issue I believed for ag-grid not displaying, was actually working. Added   `domLayout: 'autoHeight'` and the table appeared!
The code above was working to split the values and display correct colours.